# Expected resource of type anim when using ternary operator

Tags: android, android-lint

This is a very silly compiler error, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way of suppressing it (such as with an annotation) ?

The error occurs on the 2nd argument of `setCustomAnimations()`. The error is: `Expected resource of type anim`.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

int exit_animation = current_popup == null ? 0 : current_popup.getExitAnimation();

transaction.setCustomAnimations( fragment.getEnterAnimation(), exit_animation ); //ERROR
```

If I expand the ternary line to either of the following, the error disappears.

```
int exit_animation;

if ( current_popup == null )
    exit_animation = 0;
else
    exit_animation = current_popup.getExitAnimation();
```

Or:

```
int exit_animation = 0;

if ( current_popup != null )
    exit_animation = current_popup.getExitAnimation();
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but can you add the `@AnimRes` annotation to `exit_animation`? I don't know if that works on local variables.

Comment: @CommonsWare Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If you get a chance, answer your own question and show the syntax. Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to suppressing the error is:

```
@AnimRes
int exit_animation = current_popup == null ? 0 : current_popup.getExitAnimation();
```

Credit to CommonsWare in the comments.